# Rails I18n: setting initial locale from HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes, http-accept-language

Thanks everyone for your help.

**WHAT I AM DOING:**
I'm designing a corporate website which must be available in multiple languages

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**
A rails application with several static pages. I used Ryan Bates example on using I18n features in rails, in particular using routes to set the locale:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root to: 'static_pages#home'

    match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  end

  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}/%{path}")  
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}")
```

My ApplicationController looks as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale

  private
    def set_locale      
        I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end    

    def default_url_options(options = {})
        {locale: I18n.locale}
    end       
end
```

My log at server start displays the following:

```
Started GET "/en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-14 22:41:01 +0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendered static_pages/home.en.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Compiled custom.css  (5905ms)  (pid 9864)
Compiled application.css  (15ms)  (pid 9864)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6741ms (Views: 6740.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**
I would like that when a user does not specify the locale in the url (e.g. types only www.example.com), rails get the accepted locales from `request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first`
and redirects the visitor to his preferred language. At this point I can't figure out where my I18n.locale is set in the first place.

Comment: Has there been any answer to this issue. I am half way there - however, the locale gets set before I get to set_locale which is in my applicaiton controller ....

Answer (score 1):

This works magic [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language/tree/master)

Another to consider [Locale Setter](https://github.com/jcasimir/locale_setter)

The latter one allows you to check for user preference, http_accept_lang code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on exactly the same case as yours! perhaps you should [try this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-client-supplied-information)

Also refer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310812/set-locale-automatically-in-ruby-on-rails) where there are useful answers.

Once I get this working I will post an answer