# Auto detect of localization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got a rails web app, that currently support 4 languages, English is the default one,
Is there a way to know where is the user from, and change the language without his action of clicking the relevant language?

Comment: Check answer for duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310812/set-locale-automatically-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Browser Detection Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707400/rails-browser-detection-methods)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to detect a locale by a user IP address and if there's no luck then extract it from a browser settings.

1) **IP address**

Get a DB from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/

```
GeoIP.new('db/GeoIP.dat').country(request.remote_ip).country_code2
```

2) **browser language**

```
request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].to_s.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
```

Comment: Oh please please please skip step (1). Always use the browser language;  it's the user's preferred locale. Never use the IP address to set language; it's where the user just happens to be at the moment.

Comment: That said, the link to the maxmind geo DB is much appreciated. Better than relying on a remote service to translate IPs into country names.

Comment: Disagree. I prefere english language in any software, but I prefer to read site on my native language if it has one. The same situation for many of my friends.